# python class managing in another class

Tags: python, function, class

I have a class called martCrawler which import other 3 crawlers from other files

However, the code becomes too long as the crawler imported increased.

Is there a better practice managing the code like this?

Thanks in advance~

```
from Scripts_mart.wat_ver2 import crawler_watsons
from Scripts_mart.cosmed_ver1 import crawler_cosmed
from Scripts_mart.pxmart_ver1 import crawler_pxmart

import datetime

class martCrawler():

    def __init__(self):
        self.wat = crawler_watsons()
        self.cos = crawler_cosmed()
        self.pxm = crawler_pxmart()

    def crawler_testing(self):
        result_pack = {}
        wat_result = self.wat.run_before_insert()
        cos_result = self.cos.run_before_insert()
        pxm_result = self.pxm.run_before_insert()

        result_pack['wat'] = wat_result
        result_pack['cos'] = cos_result
        result_pack['pxm'] = pxm_result

        return result_pack
...
```

Comment: *"However, the code becomes too long as the crawler imported increased."* Sorry, what does that mean?

Comment: I suppose it means when they import many crawlers they will have to write many repetitive lines, ie. typing `run_before_insert()` multiple times.

Comment: Hi @Aran-Fey, sorry for misunderstanding, just as KyrSt said, there will be too many repetitive lines as the crawler imported increased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then why not store all the crawlers in a dict from the beginning?
As an example:

```
from Scripts_mart.wat_ver2 import crawler_watsons
from Scripts_mart.cosmed_ver1 import crawler_cosmed
from Scripts_mart.pxmart_ver1 import crawler_pxmart

class MartCrawler():

    def __init__(self, *args):        
        self.crawlers = {}
        for crawler in args:
            # use some introspection to get the name of the classes. 
            # The names should be "crawler_watsons", etc
            self.crawlers[crawler.__name__] = crawler() 


    def crawler_testing(self):
        result_pack = {}
        for name, crawler in self.crawlers.items():
            result_back[name] = crawler.run_before_insert()
        return result_back


martCrawler = MartCrawler(crawler_watsons, crawler_cosmed, crawler_pxmart)
```

Just have in mind that the names in your dict will be the actual names of the imported classes, not 'wat', 'pos' and 'pxm'. But if this is a problem you can use some string manipulation and/or regexes to fix it.

For example you could replace `crawler.__name__` with `crawler.__name__[8:11]`

Comment: Hm, I actually like this approach more than my own ._.

Comment: Hi, the code `result_pack[name] = crawler.run_before_insert()` has error as below:
TypeError: run_before_insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'. Since I don't fully understand the logic behind, is it similar to @Fabian N. ?

Comment: Some brackets were missing, I added them `crawler()` please try again. KyrSt solution is more pythonic but its a bit harder to read than my naive approach.

Comment: Hi, it works, but there is a problem in the key value of self.crawler, the value of `__class__.__name__` are 'type' rather than the actual class name, which as a result only the last crawler (pxmart_crawler) will be run.

Comment: Ah sry that's my mistake, KyrSt intended to call this with the instances and not the types as I assumed so the code was correct just the comment was misleading... now it should work... I also added an example for the mentioned string manipulation (hopefully @KyrSt doesn't mind)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out those mistakes. I fast typed the code without that much of proofreading. Of course I don't mind the editing. That's the point of the community in SO.

Answer (score 1):

Just put them into a dictionary:

```
from Scripts_mart.wat_ver2 import crawler_watsons
from Scripts_mart.cosmed_ver1 import crawler_cosmed
from Scripts_mart.pxmart_ver1 import crawler_pxmart

import datetime

class martCrawler():

    def __init__(self):
        self.crawlers = {
            "wat": crawler_watsons(), 
            "cos": crawler_cosmed(),
            "pxm": crawler_pxmart()
        }

    def crawler_testing(self):
        result_pack = {}
        for key in self.crawlers:
            result_pack[key] = self.crawlers[key].run_before_insert()

        return result_pack
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for solution, it works, but I would also like to understand more about the solution from @KyrSt.

Comment: There are three differences: first, @KyrSt allows you to dynamically just put all the crawlers you want into the `MartCrawler(...)` call (see here https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/). Second, instead of using keys you define, it uses the name of the classes itself so you basically get `result_pack[name_of_class_of_this_crawler] = ...`. And third, the usage of `crawlers.items()` in the for loop allowing you to do exactly the same as me just in a more readable way (see here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_items.htm).